# How to get the onscreen keybord appear on login

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, 13.10, accessibility, onscreen-keyboard

I am using Lubuntu 13.10 and I have missing keys on my keyboard. I am using a friend keyboard currently and I want to know how to get the onscreen keyboard to appear on the login screen so I can use my laptop anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

Lubuntu does not come with a screen keyboard installed, nor is the option enabled on the log-in screen by default or even after installing a virtual keyboard.

So first, install a screen keyboard. I recommend Onboard, the default in Ubuntu. Open a Terminal window and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install onboard
```

Type your password and hit enter. When that's done processing, you need to enable it on the login screen. A simple matter of editing a config file to tell it you have a keyboard that it can use. Enter the following in your Terminal window:

In Lubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

In Lubuntu 15.10:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/30_lubuntu.conf
```

You can substitute "leafpad" (the default text editor in Lubuntu) with the editor of your choice. Scroll to the bottom and you should see a line like:

```
#keyboard=
```

You just have to specify onboard and then un-comment the line by removing the hash symbol before "keyboard" like so:

```
keyboard=onboard
```

Now save the file and close the editor. To test it, just log out. You'll be back at the login screen. Click the *Universal Access* icon (the little man), then *On Screen Keyboard*. If everything's set up right, onboard should now appear on your screen.

[image: Where to find the On Screen Keyboard option]

[image: Onboard is activated]

Answer (score 2):

Just click on **Virtual Keyboard** in the **Universal Access** indicator from the top-right of your screen:

[image: Virtual Keyboard]

Comment: On my lubuntu you can also access this on the start menu bottom left, Universal Access has its own menu there

Answer (score 1):

To always enable the keyboard on start add the following into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/30_lubuntu.conf`

```
a11y-states=+keyboard
```

Comment: Can i set the option of onbaord? After the log in is set with some option. During the log in is with the default, i would like to set different options.