# How to boot 32-bit EFI

Tags: boot, uefi, 32-bit, support

I have a tablet here with Windows on it, 32-bit processor, UEFI only, no options to support bios/legacy boot modes.

I have been looking since yesterday about options when it comes to go all Frankenstein and patch together a 32-bit efi by yourself.

Sadly enough I tried to do just that, but the UEFI would not notice the USB-stick as bootable, even though i moved all the parts from the EFI & boot folders.

Sorry if I am not making much sense right now, I will give more proper information about what I've done once I'm online on my work computer, unless you understand what I mean and can post something that I can do from a windows computer?

I want to not lubuntu 32-bit with uefi

Thank you for taking you time!

Answer (score 0):

I already answer in this other question [Cannot install ubuntu Kylin 32bit on mini winpad laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943867/cannot-install-ubuntu-kylin-32bit-on-mini-winpad-laptop).
I did it in another tablet with Lubuntu amd64.
After i made a custom kernel i was able to use the touch almost perfectly (see above).
The wi-fi is working (by default) but no microphone, camera, speakers, bluetooth, and the touch hold function (for right click) is not the best.
Set `onboard` to appears in the login [How to get the onscreen keybord appear on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369621/how-to-get-the-onscreen-keybord-appear-on-login#657065) (see all the answers).
And set `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse secondary-click-enabled "true"` (hold left mouse for right click) and activate hover click in onboard.